# Create a column which increments based on another column in Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table

I've currently switched my focus from R to Python. I work with data.table in R a lot, and I find it sometimes quite difficult to find an equivalent for some functions in Python.

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['abc','def', 'def', 'abc', 'def', 'def','abc'],'B':[13123,45,1231,463,142131,4839, 4341]})
>
> > ```
> >      A       B  
> > 0  abc   13123    
> > 1  def      45  
> > 2  def    1231  
> > 3  abc     463  
> > 4  def  142131  
> > 5  def    4839
> > 6  abc    4341
> > ```

I need to create a column that increments from 1 based on A and B, so that it indicates the increasing order of B. So I first create the sorted data frame, and the column I'm interested in creating is C as below:

> ```
>     A       B   C
> 1  abc     463  1
> 6  abc    4341  2
> 0  abc   13123  3
> 3  def      45  1
> 2  def    1231  2
> 5  def    4839  3
> 4  def  142131  4
> ```

In R, using the library(data.table), this can be easily done in one line and creates a column within the original data table:

> df[, C := 1:.N, by=A]

I've looked around and I think I might be able to make use of something like this:

> df.groupby('A').size()
>   or
>   df['B'].argsort()

but not sure how to proceed from here, and how to join the new column back to the original data frame. It would be very helpful if anyone could give me any pointer.

Many thanks!

Comment: That appears to be incorrect `data.table` syntax. Do you mean `df[,C:=1:.N,by=A]`? And why `setkey` first, you can just leave it to an ad hoc by.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've corrected the typo in R code. Thanks for pointing it out. Anyway, I'm more interested in finding a way to do this in Python.

Comment: That's still wrong. That'll copy the _whole_ of `df` which is one of the (somewhat poor) features of R's `data.frame` that `data.table` improves. You can't have used `data.table` very much, to have missed this.

Comment: That's just a small data table for the sake of demonstration, and I don't see much point of focusing on this while I'm looking for a Python solution. Thanks for your R knowledge input.

Comment: Because `:=` by group is a main feature of `data.table`. You've posted to a python and pandas tag, so as the author of `data.table` I don't like to see `data.table` used badly in front of a wide audience.

Comment: Okay, sure. I got your point. I've modified the R code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [61]: df
Out[61]:
     A       B
1  abc     463
6  abc    4341
0  abc   13123
3  def      45
2  def    1231
5  def    4839
4  def  142131

In [62]: df['C'] =  df.groupby('A')['A'].transform(lambda x: pd.Series(range(1, len(x)+1), index=x.index))

In [63]: df
Out[63]:
     A       B  C
1  abc     463  1
6  abc    4341  2
0  abc   13123  3
3  def      45  1
2  def    1231  2
5  def    4839  3
4  def  142131  4
```

Comment: That works (except that the sorted data frame is actually different). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Started from frame sorted on A only, i edited this order is now the same as in example.

Comment: Hi Wouter, thanks for your thorough answer. As a follow-up question, how can I create a column ['D'] which enumerates from the minimum value of B, so that it looks like:  [463, 464, 465, 45, 46, 47, 48] in this case? (Sorry for not knowing how to format it correctly in comment!)

Comment: Actually, I think I've figured it out: `df['D'] =  df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: pd.Series(range(min(x), min(x)+len(x)), index=x.index))`  works well! (I've also figured out how to format in comment too)

Answer (score 1):

And for comparison, the correct `data.table` syntax is :

```
df[, C := 1:.N, by=A]
```

This adds a new column C by reference to `df`. The `:=` operator is part of the `data.table` package for R. It allows you to add and remove columns and assign to subsets of `data.table`, by group, by reference with no copy at all.

Comment: Is there a quick name for the dual of this operation? Say, if I want to unwrap a repeating increasing sequence, instead of repeating each time a column changes value. (If it's not a quick answer, please let me know and I'll make it a question. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

Index magic seems to be another way:

```
df['C']=df.sort(['A','B'],inplace=True).groupby('A').reset_index().index.labels[1]
```